# React on docker-compose: ERROR [3/6] COPY package.json ./

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Trying to launch React within a docker-compose environment. It always gives me errors about not being able to copy or find `package.json`. Here are my files:

```
# React Dockerfile
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/react/

# add node_modules to $PATH
ENV PATH /node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . .

# start app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

```
# docker-compose.yaml
  ...
  react:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: react/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/react'
      - '/react/node_modules'
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - drf
  ...
```

File structure:

[image]

I've seen some threads on SO and other resources, none of them were able to help, unfortunately.
As a piece of additional info, I've tried using this for copying `package.json`:

`COPY package*.json .`

It lets me make a build but still refuses to run react container because it can't find the `package.json` file.

Comment: Your `docker-compose.yml` specifies `build: { context: . }`, and then the Dockerfile `COPY package.json` from the context directory.  Is the React application in fact in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: @DavidMaze docker-compose is one directory higher. But if I put `./react` into context, it gives me an error that can't find anything in `react/react`. Apparently, it adds `/react` to the address 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution pretty quickly after posting this question. Thanks to David in comments giving me a hint.
In `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
build:
  context: ./react
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Instead of previous

```
build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: react/Dockerfile
```

Apparently, dockerfile address also adds to context address.